# Blueprint error in Flask: NameError: name of blueprint is not defined

Tags: python, flask

I am just getting started with Flask and have been working on a very simple site to get acquainted with its main features before adding other stuff on and I'm getting, what seems to me, an inscrutable problem. I've looked at numerous tutorials and have no idea where I'm  going wrong. My site directory is very simple:

```
home/user/website_name
├── ock/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── .env
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   └── home.html
│   └── static/
│       └── style.css
├── instance/
│   └── config.py
├── venv/
├── setup.py
└── wsgi.py
```

`__init__.py` is here:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

def make_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True) 
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    
    from . import routes
    app.register_blueprint(pages)
```

`routes.py` is here:

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint
from wsgi import app


bp = Blueprint(
    'pages', __name__, 
    template_folder='templates', 
    static_folder='static'
)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template(
        'home.html', 
    )
```

When I try to go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/home, it spit out: NameError: name 'pages' is not defined.

Edit to clarify question: How to do I get the blueprint to be recognized by Flask?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to import `bp` and register that `app.register_blueprint(bp)`
`

Comment: @Matt Not sure what you mean, I switched it ```app.register_blueprint(bp)``` like you said, which registers it, but isn't it correct to import routes? It seems like the problem is with the line ```from . import routes```, because VS Code tells me that it isn't used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work. All I did was modify  `app.register_blueprint(pages)` to `app.register_blueprint(routes.pages)`. I guess that told Flask where to look for the blueprint?

So much left to learn.